# Get value from table to use it in insert

Tags: sql, sqlite

I suppose this question was already asked somewhere here, but I have no idea how to name (and look for) it correctly.

The database:

```
CREATE TABLE department (
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
    id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    department_id INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    chief_id      INTEGER,
    name          VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    salary        INTEGER      NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES department (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (chief_id) REFERENCES employee (id)
);

INSERT INTO department (name) VALUES ('sales'), ('it'), ('management');

INSERT INTO employee (department_id, chief_id, name, salary) VALUES
    (3, NULL, 'Owner', 1000000),
    (2, 1, 'Team manager', 9000),
    (2, 3, 'Senior dev #1', 7000),
    (2, 3, 'Senior dev #2', 7000);
```

Now in insert I should calculate `chief_id` on my own, but I'm curious if there is a possibility to get id by name, something like

```
SELECT id FROM employee WHERE name = 'Owner'
```

and use this value instead of hardcoded id in insert.

I've tried putting select statement instead of id but that does not work.

I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery as yours, but the data has to be in the table before you can select it. Otherwise the subquery returns null. So you need to break the one `INSERT` into multiple `INSERT`s.

```
INSERT INTO employee (department_id, chief_id, name, salary) VALUES
    (3, NULL, 'Owner', 1000000);

INSERT INTO employee (department_id, chief_id, name, salary) VALUES    
    (2, (SELECT id FROM employee WHERE name = 'Owner'), 'Team manager', 9000);

INSERT INTO employee (department_id, chief_id, name, salary) VALUES
    (2, (SELECT id FROM employee WHERE name = 'Team manager'), 'Senior dev #1', 7000),
    (2, (SELECT id FROM employee WHERE name = 'Team manager'), 'Senior dev #2', 7000);
```

But note, that the subquery must return only one row. So the column you're checking in it's `WHERE` clause must contain unique values. Usually a name is not unique, there are a lot of John Smith. Usually the ID is the unique identifier. So in a general inserting the ID directly is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was very close but did not knew about brackets and got syntax error